# How do you convert encoding from UTF-8 to windows-1252?

Tags: encoding, ansi, iconv, windows-1252

How can I correctly convert a text file from UTF-8 to Windows-1252?

I have tried converting the file using iconv (windows xp) but this util converted the text file to ANSI. The default code page in my Windows is Windows-1251 and so I can`t correctly display some characters.

Comment: `iconv` as a command line utility? As part of a programming language? With some GUI?

Comment: Is there a Windows GUI application that can convert the contents of the clipboard from UTF-8 to Windows-1252 so the user doesn't have to go through a file?

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one file to convert, I use [Notepadd++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) ...

Encoding Menu -> Character Sets -> Western Europeean

Comment: I select Encoding Menu -> Character Sets -> Western Europeean in Notepad++, but new encoding is not saved after closing the file.

Comment: "Encoding" -> "Encode in ansi" is selected, then you select European then you save and it is not kept? I don't know .. :(

Comment: If I do as you wrote, it remains in ANSI, but not in Western Europe.